# Example Evernote OAuth with python-oauth2

Tags: python, oauth, evernote

Are there any examples of authenticating to the Evernote API using [python-oauth2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGAQFjAA&url=https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2&ei=HAjgT-vuJab22AXZ3ICeCg&usg=AFQjCNHYteYI_IbCcPOMK2sLTLLywkixjw)? [They use a slightly different part of the spec](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Authentication.php) than most, which I don't think the library is built to handle natively.

Comment: I believe evernote does not have oauth2 support, only oauth1

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to suggest an alternative to python-oauth2, given that it seems largely unmaintained. Why not check out [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth)? Rauth is similar in concept, although much simpler to use and built on top of Requests, so you can expect stellar HTTP support. Now I haven't used Evernote's API, but if you check out [the examples](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples), there's both OAuth 1.0/a and 2.0. Those should get you started.

If you're stuck with python-oauth2, I'm sure Googling will turn up a number of examples. But if you can, I'd go for a newer, maintained library. Rauth is just one option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Python SDK https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python which provides a class `EvernoteClient` and a function `get_request_token` which will check/request the token provided by the Evernote user's account.

I deal all of this with django like this https://github.com/foxmask/django-th-evernote/blob/master/th_evernote/my_evernote.py#L146

I hope this could help.

Comment: The django-th-evernote seems missing on github